# How to convert a timestamp string into datetime in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I was doing some data-check for 1-2 months old data in my sql server and a question rised in my mind.

I made a string `926084711140` and `20210926084711140` which I am considering to be a date-time stamp.

I thought of converting into actual datetime value. So I tried this:

`'2021-' + SUBSTRING(CAST(th.edit_timestamp as varchar(50)),1,1) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CAST(th.edit_timestamp as varchar(50)),2,2)`

And this returned a value `2021-09-.2` I am unable to understand this output.

I thought of doing substring but so far it failed.

Can anyone help regarding this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What part don't you understand? It is just doing a couple of substrings. But the real question is what is that absurd string??? Why not use the datetime datatype instead of the string nightmare you have going on. Also, your code is going to fail once you get to a 2 digit month.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have stated - you should fix your data model, but here is an alternative method:

```
Select cast(stuff(stuff(stuff(stuff(@date, 15, 0, '.'), 13, 0, ':'), 11, 0, ':'), 9, 0, ' ') as datetime)
```

And if you really have the first date format without the year you can do this:

```
Select cast(stuff(stuff(stuff(stuff(concat('2021', right(concat('0', @date), 13)), 15, 0, '.'), 13, 0, ':'), 11, 0, ':'), 9, 0, ' ') as datetime)
```

Comment: Hi @Jeff. Thanks for replying. I tried the second solution you gave above as I do have a date format without a year. It is giving me a ```Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string``` error. I tried to check the output a little closely so I removed the casting. The conversion is giving this output:
```202109.2 60:85:e+-011```
Are we missing something here? Also, if I may, the conversion is giving the same output of 202109.2 60....... where it should give 2021-09-26 08:50....... something.
But appreciate the effort. I think you are pretty close.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - been quite busy at work.  You need to validate the input is in the correct format to be converted.  Check what that column looks like before you attempt to convert it and I would guess it isn't as you expect.  You can also use try_cast - which will return a null value if it cannot convert the value.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'm going to tell you is: don't use this format. You have to fix the data input, don't try to fix the data output

But if there is no other way ...
I'm going to assume that your format is
aaaa-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm

We can do something like this

```
select convert(datetime,'2021-09-26T08:47:11.140',126)
```

OUTPUT: 2021-09-26 08:47:11.140

```
declare @date varchar(50) = '20210926084711140'

select convert(datetime,substring(@date,1,4) + '-' + substring(@date,5,2) + '-' 
+ substring(@date,7,2) + 'T' + substring(@date,9,2) + ':' + 
substring(@date,11,2) + ':' + substring(@date,13,2) + '.' + 
substring(@date,15,3),126)
```

one more time ... this is horrible.

try to fix your data source and not work with this.

Good luck